# fortimail antispam has blacklisted the internal exchange mail server address

Tags: spam, blacklist, fortinet

i have an exchange server for which i wanted to redirect  outbound messages throught a fortimail antispam box. i created a new send connector for a test domain and used the ip of the antispam as the smart host.

i am already using the antispam for inbound messages.

the message dont get out off the antispam.  (delivery delayed message from exchange)
after a few moment the internal ip was blacklistest. 
i cannot connect to smtp port , the session is immediately closed

i have the following message in the logs :

```
Log Type    AntiSpam
Date    2016-06-29
Time    10:54:46
Client  mail.domain.local [192.0.10.48]
Message FortiGuard-AntiSpam identified spam ip at connection: score=3
Log ID  0300019726
Level   information
Type    spam
Destination IP  192.168.99.1
```

i tryed to create a RELAY access control policy to allow relaying from this ip. i also added the ip into the system white list.
But i still cannot connect to the antispam box on port 25

how can i get out of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it sorted.

I didn't notice another restrictrive rule was set before my relay rule. 
I changed the rule order and now i can enter again the box.

Thankx